# fstab ssh mount eating network and CPU

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mount, nas, fstab

I've recently bought a NAS (WD MyCloud) and connected it to my router. I'm able to see it on the network and connceting through SSH. I was also able to put an fstab entry to automount a folder in my computer. I transfered some files to it and everything was fine. Today, I notice that this mount is constantly using 5-10 MB/s of incoming bandwidth and 5% of CPU, even when I'm not using it (not reading, not even opening any folder of the mount point).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

The fstab entry is :

```
NASUSER@NASHOSTNAME:/shares/Multimedia /data/Multimedia  fuse.sshfs _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,users,idmap=user,port=XXXX,IdentityFile=/PATH/TO/IDENTITY/FILE,allow_other,reconnect 0 0
```

The process that eats ressources is :

```
ssh -x -a -oClearAllForwardings=yes -oport=XXXX -oIdentityFile=/PATH/TO/IDENTITY/FILE -2 NASUSER@NASHOSTNAME
```

Some help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And the question is? That is a lot of traffic for keepalive messages.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I thought the question/problem was clear. Why is there so much traffic/ CPU used ? And how can I change that. I cannot believe that keep alive messages take  10MB/s.

Comment: That would be certainly weird. But without further investigation, what is going on there, there is no way how to help you. You can attach `gdb` or `perf` to the running process on your computer, you can check if there are some logs on the server, you can check if there is not some other process constantly writing into your mounted directory. A lot of possibilities.

Comment: @J.Mo : Are you still looking at this problem? I have noticed my WD myCloud is doing a storm of `smb(2?)` traffic, listing all files on the WD over and over :-/ . I have spend some time trying to solve it, but haven't found the right answer yet. You could install/use wireshare, start a capture session and type `smb` in the filter "box" at the top left of the screen to see if you have the same problem. You may also see `smb` at the "top" of the list if you run the `top` utility from cmd-line on your WD. My `smb` consumes about 100% of 1 (of the 2) CPUs. Others have claimed even higher. GoodLuck